# Eclipse Plug-in Development with JavaFX 2 and JRE 1.6

Tags: eclipse, plugins, deployment, javafx

I'm developing an Eclipse Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 and above (having JavaSE-1.6 as prerequisite for the end user)

I would like to incorporate some JavaFX 2 capabilities into the UI, but i'm having trouble with deployment of the plugin. i believe i'm not configuring the libs correctly, or not including jfxrt.jar somehow somewhere.

There is some material online about incorporating JavaJX 2 with a current project, but i can't seem to figure out how to **deploy** it with the plugin deployment.

I tried all sorts of things, but before i spill everything here - the question is, if i'm aiming for a feasible goal?

thanks

Comment: So it works while you are launching an INNER Eclipse but not when you export? 

We at e(fx)clipse used to support JavaSE 1.6 to some extend in previous versions but stopped supporting it because JavaFX 2 on JDK6 only works on Win32/64 and now we only support JavaFX 2 + JDK7 and JavaFX8/JDK8.

Our way of supporting fx is not to repackage but to use AdapterHooks instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I am writing a plugin aiming for 1.6 and 1.7 users on all OS's. Your answer obsoletes usage of JavaFX 2 for that purpose. So now, its raw SWT for me ...